# Do you recognize this sequence of polynomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics, orthogonal-polynomials

In teaching my linear algebra students about Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, I found a curious sequence of polynomials.  They are closely related to Legendre polynomials, but they also appear to be related to Catalan numbers.  (Several of the statements below are conjectural and I am not an expert on orthogonal polynomials, so please bear with me.)

Recall that if we apply the Gram-Schmidt process to the sequence $\{1,t,t^2,t^3,...\}$, where the inner product is given by $\left<f,g\right>=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t)dt$, then one obtains a the Legendre polynomials.

Doing Gram-Schmidt for the first time is always a pain, and I wanted to make the problem easier to do by hand by choosing the initial basis in such a way to avoid a lot of uncomfortable fractions.  I gave my students the set $\{1,2t,6t^2,20t^3\}$ and told them to use the inner product $\left<f,g\right>=\int_{0}^1 f(t)g(t)dt$.  (This yields a sort of "shifted" version of the Legendre polynomials.)  Notice that the coefficients of these monomials are the "central" binomial coefficients $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$.  If we apply Gram-Schmidt to these, then we get the polynomials $\{1,2t-1,6t^2-6t+1,20t^3-30t^2+12t-1\}$.  (In spite of my efforts, one of my students declared that, upon finding these, he could no longer feel joy.)

The new polynomials that I want to know about are obtained by writing these "shifted" Legendre polynomials as linear combinations of the initial polynomials.  Thus, in this instance, we have
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
t-1 \\
6t^2-6t+1 \\
20t^3-30t^2+12t-1 \\
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 6 & -5 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2t \\
6t^2 \\
20t^3 \\
\end{array}\right].$$
We use the coefficient matrix here to define a new sequence by
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
f_0 \\
f_1 \\
f_2 \\
f_3 \\
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 6 & -5 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
t \\
t^2 \\
t^3 \\
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
t-1 \\
t^2-3t+1 \\
t^3-5t^2+6t-1 \\
\end{array}\right].$$
I hope that the reader now understands how to define $f_n$ for all $n$.  Use the coefficients that are required to write the orthogonal polynomials with respect to the monomials $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}t^n$.

My first thought about these was that they should also be a sequence of orthogonal polynomials.  They seem to have the root-interlacing property, although the roots appear to be unbounded.  This makes me think that they are related to Laguerre polynomials.  (The roots of the Legendre polynomials are necessarily between -1 and 1.)  Also, these polynomials seem to obey the (very nice) 3-term recurrence $tf_n=f_{n-1}+2f_n+f_{n+1}$ for $n=1,2,3,4,....$

This is where the Catalan numbers seem to appear.  Recall that the $n$th Catalan number is $C_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}.$  If we had an inner product on the space of polynomials such that $\left<t^i,t^j\right>=C_{i+j}$, then applying the Gram-Schmidt process to the sequence $\{1,t,t^2,t^3,t^4,...\}$ appears to yield the sequence $f_n$.  Is there a function $g$ such that $\int_0^\infty t^n g(t)dt=C_n$?  I am guessing that such $g$ should be defined on $[0,\infty)$ because of the behavior of the roots of $f_n$.

What are these polynomials called?

Comment: The integral representation
$$C_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^4 t^n \sqrt{\frac{4-t}{t}}\, dt$$
can be found in 
https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/SIXDENIERS/Catalan.html, 
though I am sure it is much older.

Comment: Ira:  This looks very promising.  This makes me think that one can get a special case of the Jacobi polynomials from the Legendre polynomials (which I realize are also another special case of Jacobi polynomials) using this transformation that I describe in the original post.  (I wish I knew more about these transformations in general.)  If this works, then this would mean that the roots of my polynomials always lie in the interval (0,4).  Thank-you.  Now I will tinker around with this some more.

Comment: It might be noted that this integral is, up to normalization, a special case of the beta integral. The general beta integral corresponds to Jacobi polynomials (though with a different normalization than usual).

Comment: Relations among the Gegenbauer, Jacobi, Legendre, and the polynomials highlighted in this post can be found in the OEIS entries to which I linked in my answer.

Comment: Do your students a service by introducing them to the OEIS if you haven't already. If they don't find the numerous connections interesting, I suggest they pursue a major outside of STEM.

Comment: Following on Ira Gessel's comments one might note that this is the simplest case of the _super ballot numbers_. A generalization of the integral formula is given in OEIS [A135573](https://oeis.org/A135573).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $b_n(t)$ be the Morgan-Voyce polynomial defined by $$\begin{eqnarray}b_0(t) &=& 1 \\
b_1(t) &=& t + 1 \\
b_n(t) &=& (t+2) b_{n-1}(t) - b_{n-2}(t)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then $f_n(t) = (-1)^n b_n(-t)$ fits your recurrence.

See [Rising diagonal polynomials associated with Morgan-Voyce polynomials](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.376.3755&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Swamy, M. N., Fibonacci Quarterly 38.1 (2000) pp61-69 for an overview of these polynomials which includes the following observations:

- $b_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{n-k} t^k$ (2.10)
- The zeros of $b_n(t)$ are $-4 \sin^2 \left(\frac{2r-1}{2n+1} \frac{\pi}2 \right)$ for $r = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ (2.14)
- $b_n(t)$ is orthogonal over $(-4,0)$ with respect to the weight function $\sqrt{-(t+4)/t}$ (2.26)

---

In light of that the following is largely superfluous, but...

From $b_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{n-k} t^k$ we can test that we get the original "shifted" Legendre polynomials, and since each transformation in the process which gives $f_n$ is invertible that would validate the conjectured identity of the $f_n$. Denote the polynomials which come from the Gram-Schmidt process as $u_n$, so $$u_n(t) = \binom{2n}{n}t^n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left<u_j,\binom{2n}{n}t^n\right>}{\left<u_j,u_j\right>} u_j(t)$$

Then the conjecture is that $$\begin{eqnarray*}u_n(t) \stackrel?= \tilde{f_n}(t) &:=& \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} t^k [t^k] f_n(t) \\
%&=& (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k} t^k [t^k] b_n(-t) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{n+k}{n-k} t^k \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

##### Product with original basis function

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left<\tilde{f_j}, \binom{2n}{n}t^n\right> &=& \int_0^1 \tilde{f_j} \binom{2n}{n}t^n dt \\
&=& \binom{2n}{n} \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{j+k}{j-k} t^{k+n} dt \\
&=& \binom{2n}{n} \sum_{k=0}^j \frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{k+n+1} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{j+k}{j-k} \\
&=& \frac{1}{n+j+1} \binom{2n}{n-j}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

with [some help from Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdizkOgDAMwHZekY2kTQVl5ytIsDWhAZXj_ZQRRlu2sLHCCPdcsJUXWmr2kuzE48qIIdKE4pXAwZJsy2lecXDG9jPK36Y-LKG6DtC8-kgMytAzCNEDAbMhMw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

##### Self-product

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left<\tilde{f_j}, \tilde{f_j}\right> &=& \int_0^1 \tilde{f_j}^2 dt \\
&=& \int_0^1 \tilde{f_j} \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{j+k}{j-k} t^k dt \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j+k}{j-k} \int_0^1 \tilde{f_j} \binom{2k}{k} t^k dt \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j+k}{j-k} \frac{1}{k+j+1} \binom{2k}{k-j}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the term in the sum has support only when $j=k$, yielding $$\left<\tilde{f_j}, \tilde{f_j}\right> = \frac{1}{2j+1}$$

##### Gram-Schmidt induction

If we assume that $u_j = \tilde{f_j}$ for all $j < n$ then

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
u_n(t) &=& \binom{2n}{n}t^n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left<\tilde{f_j},\binom{2n}{n}t^n\right>}{\left<\tilde{f_j},\tilde{f_j}\right>} \tilde{f_j}(t) \\
&=& \binom{2n}{n}t^n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{2j+1}{n+j+1} \binom{2n}{n-j} \tilde{f_j}(t) \\
&=& \binom{2n}{n}t^n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{2j+1}{n+j+1} \binom{2n}{n-j} \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{j+k}{j-k} t^k \\
&=& \binom{2n}{n}t^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{2k}{k} t^k  \sum_{j=k}^{n-1} (-1)^{j+1} \frac{2j+1}{n+j+1} \binom{2n}{n-j} \binom{j+k}{j-k} \\
% subst j: = n-j
&=& \binom{2n}{n}t^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+k} \binom{2k}{k} t^k  \sum_{j=1}^{n-k} (-1)^{j+1} \frac{2n-2j+1}{2n-j+1} \binom{2n}{j} \binom{n-j+k}{n-j-k} \\
&=& \binom{2n}{n}t^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+k} \binom{2k}{k} t^k  
\binom{n+k}{n-k} \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{n+k}{n-k} t^k
\end{eqnarray*}$$

with [some more help from Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVizsSgCAMBXtPkY6AyTjQexVnsCNIdPBzfkUru7c7-4QyKYxwxYpGGhjbdVtNeuB-FkT2dkLpvQUHc9K1pLhgcEryM8rSP2cWzs23goN7f8NHbRMIgSfQp7I3VNogng==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) for one of the sums.

Comment: Peter:  I find this satisfactory, although the last line should say $=\tilde{f}_n(t)$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The recurrence $f_{n+1} = (t-2)f_n - f_{n-1}$ with $f_0=1$ and $f_1=t-1$ suggests that $f_n$ can be expressed in terms of [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) as:
\begin{split}
f_n(t) &= T_n(\tfrac{t}2-1) + \frac{t}{2} U_{n-1}(\tfrac{t}2-1) \\
&=U_n(\tfrac{t}2-1) + U_{n-1}(\tfrac{t}2-1),
\end{split}
and so their orthogonality and other properties should follow from those of Chebyshev polynomials.

Answer (score 5):

See OEIS [A129818](https://oeis.org/A129818) and the unsigned version [A085478](https://oeis.org/A085478) as well as [A049310](https://oeis.org/A049310), [A011973](https://oeis.org/A011973), and [A054142](https://oeis.org/A054142).

Relations among the Gegenbauer, Jacobi, Legendre, and the polynomials highlighted in this post can be found in OEIS [A097610](https://oeis.org/A097610) via A011973 and A049310.

[A102426](https://oeis.org/A102426), [A030528](https://oeis.org/A030528), A011973, A049310 contain relations to the Pascal, Fibonacci, Chebyshev, and other polynomials.

Comment: There is an abundance of information in the OEIS entries and their refs/links to be had if you have the flexibility of mind and discipline to explore them, including connections to free probability, random matrices, and the Cauchy/Hilbert transform for generating moments.